# How to create custom Routing in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need help with URL rewriting. I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC. When I type  anything in `{param}` part then routing should redirect it to my controller.

So if anyone to types in `{param}` like

> https://mydoamin.com/{param}

then it should be redirected to this url:

> https://mydoamin.com/{controller}/{action}/{actionurl}={param}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer for my question. Just define new custom route in your startup.cs file before your default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Member",                                             // Route name
    "{actionURL}",                                        // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Pages", action = "Details" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

It's working form me.

Answer (score 3):

We can do the same using this approach.
I find this more convenient.

```
 [Http("add/user/{user}/{password}")]
 public IActionResult AddUser(string user, string password)
 {
      //do your things here...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I could recommend you to see this blog post from Stephen Walther: [ASP.NET 5 Deep Dive: Routing](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing)

I am not sure if this works as you want. `https://mydoamin.com/{controller}/{action}/{actionurl}={param}` seems not to be a valid [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) to me. The part {actionurl}={param} is probably the query part which is comes as a key/value pair and starts always with a **?**. You could probably fix your routing if your desired URL would look like `https://mydoamin.com/{controller}/{action}/?key1=value1&key2=value2`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know still this is useful OR not but in asp.net core 3 this worked for me like a charm.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MoviesByReleaseDate",
    "movies/released/{year}/{month}",
    new { controller = "Movies", action = "ByReleaseDate" }
);
```