# Asp.net Core Razor Page URL

Tags: razor, .net-core, razor-pages

I want to implement a SEO friendly URL for my ASP.NET Core Razor Page website.

Currently i have a URL like:

http://www.example.com/Post/{PostId}

but now i want to rewrite my URL like:

http://www.example.com/Post/{PostName}
Or
http://www.example.com/Post/{PostId}/{PostName}

So please anybody can help me on above...

Post.chtml :

```
@page "{id}/{postName}"
@using KianHyd.Web.Models.Services
@inject PostServices _PostServices
@{
    var id = int.Parse((string)RouteData.Values["id"]);
    var post = await _PostServices.GetPostById(id);
    ViewData["Title"] = post.Name;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37702526/6052427 like this ?

Comment: I use [Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Generating links?

Comment: When i call this url: `http://www.example.com/Post/{PostId}`, i' ll want redirect to `http://www.example.com/Post/{PostId}/{PostName}`.
i use [Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)