# Custom Routing in ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, routes, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm having trouble setting up a routing convention for Razor Pages in an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application (I'm migrating from traditional MVC to Razor Pages).

I am using the standard Pages folder structure as recommended in the documentation, but I want to customise the generated routes slightly.

For example, on a Details.cshtml page in the Products folder I have the following directive:

```
@page "{id:int}
```

The URL for this page is:

```
/Products/Details/42
```

however I want the URL to be:

```
/Products/42
```

I want this to be globally applicable, not just on the Product Details page. The documentation is not particularly clear on this.

Comment: check this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683121/how-to-create-custom-routing-in-asp-net-core

Comment: That is for Controller/Action routing, not Pages

Answer (score 1):

So this seems to be the way to do it:

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/327/customising-routing-conventions-in-razor-pages

1. Create a class that implements `IPageRouteModelConvention`:

```
public class CustomPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
            if (template.EndsWith("Details/{id:int}", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = template.Replace("Details/{id:int}", "{id:int}", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Register the class in `Startup.cs`:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
    {
        o.Conventions.Add(new CustomPageRouteModelConvention());
    });
```

Compared to the old MVC way of doing it this seems like a massive effort, but I can see that it allows for a finer level of control.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the entire route, so this is what you needed -

```
@page "/Products/{id:int}"
```

Comment: I can verify that this actually works.